# How to get a list of tcsh shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tcsh

I am currently using <kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> to know my previous command run on terminal. Similarly, there is one like <kbd>Esc</kbd>+ <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete only certain character.

I want to know more of such short-cut combos and some more information about such shortcut keys.

Comment: [Gnome-terminal Keyboard shortcuts](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/adv-keyboard-shortcuts.html.en)

Comment: @KasiyA It's a good list but why it doesn't have Esc + p  ??

also Ctrl + c does abort the current command on terminal and launch new prompt line.

Comment: That is a little old ;) as you can see in step 1 mentioned "Select Edit ▸ Preferences ▸ Shortcuts." while we have separate option for that under Edit menu as known "Keyboard shortcuts ".

Comment: @KasiyA You seem confused about the difference between a shell, and a terminal. Not only that, this question is tagged as [xterm], not [gnome-terminal]...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can list all currently active keybinds in `tcsh` with the `bindkey` command:

```
% bindkey
Standard key bindings
"^@"           ->  set-mark-command
"^A"           ->  beginning-of-line
"^B"           ->  backward-char
"^C"           ->  tty-sigintr
... etc ...
```

In this output, `^[` is the escape character this is <kbd>Esc</kbd> followed by your key (eg. <kbd>p</kbd>). Some terminal emulators may also send <kbd>Alt</kbd> as the escape character.
`M-` is Meta (<kbd>Alt</kbd>), and `^` is <kbd>Control</kbd>.

You can also use `bindkey` to set commands; See the [manpage entry on `bindkey`](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Builtin_commands.html#bindkey) for more information.

A list of keybinds for `xterm` can [be found here](http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_use_short-cut_keys_in_xterm_and_other_terminals); [the manpage](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#KEY%20BINDINGS) also has a section on it, but it's not very to-the-point...

Answer (score 0):

For bash and some other shells, you can read the [man page of readline](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?readline%203) which contains a list of possible key bindings for editing (by default the Emacs mode is used).
Some of them also work for tcsh.

Comment: I did find some of the matching ones, like the ones _beginning-of-line (C-a)_ .. but do meta key **(M-<anykey>)** means Escape key by default?

Comment: @JigarGandhi Meta is <kbd>Alt</kbd>. But often it can also be entered by first typing <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then the *anykey*.

Comment: `tcsh` doesn't use the readline library; you seem to have assumed that this is a `bash` question, which it is not (so this answer is wrong)...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker
but some of them matched perfectly!! lucky enough!!

Comment: @Carpetsmoker thanks, I made the answer more precise.